# Rails singleton client lost after a Rails crash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, singleton, ruby-on-rails-5, activesupport

I have several third party APIs I need to connect to, so I have defined an abstract module for Singleton behavior, and the specific connector singleton isntances.

My problem : everytime the Rails server crash (500 error, localhost), it seems I'm losing the @client instance variable of the connector

```
module ServiceConnector
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    include Singleton
    @activated = false
    @activation_attempt = false
    @client = nil

    def client
      @client
    end

    def service_name
      self.class.name.gsub('Connector', '')
    end

    def activate
      @activation_attempt = true
      if credentials_present?
        @client = service_client
        @activated = true
      end
      status_report
    end

class MyConnector
  include ServiceConnector
  @app_id = nil
  @api_key = nil

  def credentials_present?
    @app_id.present? and @api_key.present?
  end

  def service_client
    ::MyService::Client.new(
      app_id: @app_id,
      api_key: @api_key
    )
  end

  def set_credentials(id, key)
    @app_id = id
    @api_key = key
  end
```

I initialize my singleton in a Rails initializer

```
#config/initializers/my_connectors.rb
my_service = MyConnector.instance
if my_service_should_be_activated?
  my_service.set_credentials(
    Rails.application.secrets.app_id,
    Rails.application.secrets.api_key
  )
  my_service.activate
end

def some_action_on_client
  client.push_event(...)
end
```

The set of events

```
rails s
...
# MyConnector client Online and working fine
...
# error 500 on some controller
# (next client request)
# MyConnector @client variable mysteriously set to nil
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Rails.logger` to see if it's being initialized correctly? A crash is no different from a process restart. The singleton should be re-initialized.

Comment: Does this happen after every time the app is reloaded? When Rails reloads the app code, it does not re-execute initializers. What happens is your classes are defined, they include the concern, and then they set `@client` to nil. However, the initializer is not run, so `@client` is never assigned again. I suspect this happens after every code change, and you are only noticing it after triggering an error.

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing me to the right direction, this is most likely what happened. How would you deal with that then ? I'm going to post a solution using a different singleton pattern variant, but I'd be curious/accept answers that explain how I should write a service that gets correctly reloadedin those cases.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up rewriting the code using the Module Singleton Pattern as described [there](https://github.com/nslocum/design-patterns-in-ruby/tree/master/singleton/module_as_singleton)

Basically, it consists of just using a module and module class variables

```
module ServiceConnector
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class ConnectorError < Exception
  end

  class ActivationError < ConnectorError
  end

  included do
    @@activated = false
    @@activation_attempt = false
    @@client = nil

    # all other methods as class methods with self.

class MyConnector
  include ServiceConnector

  @@some_credential = nil

  def self.set_credentials(cred)
    @@some_credential = cred
  end

  def self.credentials_present?
    @@some_credential != nil
  end

  def self.service_client
    ::MyService.new(
      @@some_credential,
    )
  end

  # also all other methods with self.
```

And the access becomes direct with `MyConnector.some_method` instead of calling `.instance` first